# What does the gift to Chepe mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, narcos

At the end of the season 3 of *Narcos*, Miguel, who wants to gain trust from Chepe and Pacho, gives each one a precious gift.

To Pacho, he gives the secret location of the Salazars (who murdered his lover and injured his brother), so he can avenge before turning himself to the authorities.

To Chepe, he gives documents including a passport. How is that important for Chepe? Why would he need these ID documents since the Cali lords are planning to go to jail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the point you are referriing to Miguel has decided that Rodriguez's plan is no good and that surrendering to the authorities is not a viable plan.

Therefore, his intention is to NOT follow the original plan and continue in the cocaine trade.

He knows (or at least senses) that Pacho and Chepe agree with him and so offered "gifts" to further this cause.

For Chepe, specifically, the new Passport / Identity will enable Chepe to return to New York (which Chepe loves) and re-establish his base there without being identified by the US authorities as his initial identity was compromised.

Comment: But the two guys did themselves call the police to turn themselves. Pacho, just after cleaning the Salazar hideout, Chepe just after his biggest meal ever...

Comment: That happened later..because Miguel was captured. At that point, surrender was their best option.